# Sanity CMS data is not showing on the react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I was following a tutorial on youtube (https://youtu.be/3HNyXCPDQ7Q) for creating a portfolio website. I hosted the website using Netlify, 20 days later when I revisited the website, the website was just a blank screen. When I tested again on localhost, the problem was with sanity. When I connected to sanity, the screen would go blank.
Now the problem is that the regular website content is visible, but the data from sanity is not being fetched to the react app.

I have added some documents in the abouts schema via the sanity gui.

Abouts Schema:

```
export default {
  name: "abouts",
  title: "Abouts",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      title: "Title",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "description",
      title: "Description",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "imgUrl",
      title: "ImgUrl",
      type: "image",
      options: {
        hotspot: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

About.jsx code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

import "./About.scss";
import { urlFor, client } from "../../Client";
import { AppWrapper } from "../../wrapper/";

const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  const querySelector = async () => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';
    const aboutsQuery = await client.fetch(query);

    aboutsQuery.then((data) => setAbouts(data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    querySelector();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className="app__about-header"
        whileInView={{ x: [1000, 0] }}
        transition={{ duration: 1 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
      >
        <h1 className="head-text">
          <span>About</span> Me
        </h1>
      </motion.div>
      <motion.div
        className="app__about-desc"
        whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
        transition={{ duration: 1 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
      >
        <h3 style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>Who I am?</h3>
        <p className="p-text">
          Some text here.
        </p>
      </motion.div>

      <motion.div
        style={{ marginTop: 40 }}
        whileInView={{ x: [-1000, 0] }}
        transition={{ duration: 1 }}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
      >
        <h2 className="head-text">
          What I <span>Love to do?</span>
        </h2>
      </motion.div>
      <div className="app__profiles">
        {abouts.map((about, index) => {
          return (
            <motion.div
              whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
              whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1, type: "tween" }}
              className="app__profile-item"
              key={index}
              viewport={{ once: true }}
            >
              <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
              <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                {about.title}
              </h2>
              <p className="p-text">{about.description}</p>
            </motion.div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppWrapper(About, "about", "app__whitebg");
```

This Client.js file will connect to the sanity CMS.
Client.js code:

```
import SanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: "hard coded value added here",
  dataset: "portfoliodataset",
  apiVersion: "2022-08-11",
  useCdn: true,
  token: "token value here",
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I have tried the env variable as well in client.js file.
for eg. projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID
and I have tried the hard coded values as well. Both don't seem to work.

Note that I have also added the localhost:3000 and the website url in the CORS origin.

Please help me, I am stuck on this problem for a few days now.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know whether you are struck in this or not but giving you reply in case in future if someone struck at this point they can fix it. I also faced the same issue and strucked for the time being and later I realized the issue. The issue is you can't give some random name to the dataset

```
export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: "hard coded value added here",
  dataset: "portfoliodataset",
  apiVersion: "2022-08-11",
  useCdn: true,
  token: "token value here",
});
```

Here in this dataset field you have to give the dataset name which is in sanity.json file. Hope it would help you

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and I was able to fix it by doing following stuff:

1. Installing `dotenv` node package
2. Moving `.env` file to `frontend_react` folder. (I accidentally created it under src folder)

I hope that it would help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, in the same tutorial. make sure first you have internet connection, then try restarting everything even with internet on.

Its basically a network issue not withstanding any other possible cause of error, but you could give it time then later refresh the react app as well as the sanity client.

Also you could try adding some more code to give the compiler something new to compile, some how the app will load sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Check your sanity.json or sanity.config.js file (if you are using vite) and make sure the dataset you are using is the correct one. It has to match what you have in the client.js file

I had the same issue

Comment: A days work wasted just on this, you really saved me on this one. Not many answers with Vite involved and as I'm a user and love it, it does make things a little hard to search. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have import the key and run the sanity client on your localhost